# LowPower AltBeacon Scanning Clarifications

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

My goal is to understand how AltBeacon behaves and to obtain the most efficient application regarding power consumption and beacon detection.
Currently I am analysing the library and I need some clarifications.

Environment:

- Using custom beacons, not having power dependencies (on beacon HW), transmit rate (adv) is bigger than `1/s`
- Using android-beacon-library-reference with light modifications to match the custom beacons;
- Using `Android 10` OS
- All the testing was made using only `backgroundMode`

Here are my questions:

1. At initialization (using `RegionBootstrap`), we reach `ScanJobScheduler` from two points

   - `BeaconManager:startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion`: schedules an immediate ScanJob to run in `50 millis`
   - `BeaconManager:setBackgroundMode`: cancels the previous scheduled immediate ScanJob (because we are in background mode) and schedules a periodic ScanJob

     **Is the reason that immediate ScanJob get canceled because the 2nd call is made in less then 50 millis? and why the periodic ScanJob is scheduled twice?**
2. After I kill the application, it takes ~10 minutes to start again, and after another 15 minutes for the 1st scan to start.

   **Can we do one "periodic scan job" immediately after the application starts and not have to wait for 15 minutes more in order for the 1st scheduled periodic ScanJob to start?**
3. Low Power HW Filter only works after one ScanJob is completed

   - I've seen that the HW filter is installed after ScanJob Lifecycle is completed (`createScanFiltersForBeaconParsers`)
   - In the case where the application is killed, this means that the filter will be installed after the 1st periodic ScanJob completes (25 minutes)

     **Can we install the Low Power HW Filter immediately after initialization and not wait for the 1st ScanJob to complete?**
4. If I modify the ADV TX power on the custom beacon to be lower, will the distance calculator still work properly?
5. Does it makes sense to only use background mode or should I switch to foreground? Will this achieve my goal?

   - Start service in foreground
   - Install HW filter (if point 3 is not an option, do an immediate scan in foreground to trigger it)
   - Scan in background until the HW filter delivers the intent
   - Start scanning in foreground after we detect the 1st beacon
   - Scan in foreground until we are out of the region in order for the HW filter to be installed again (`startPassiveScanIfNeeded`)
   - Switch to scanning in background and wait for the next wake-up
6. Is there any possible way to receive an Intent from `BluetoothLEScanner` when the beacon is not in range?

Thanks,
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

A few answers:

1. The 50 second delay in starting the immediate scan job is designed to prevent a race condition that starts two immediate scan jobs at the same time.  When you set background mode to true, it assumes you are *changing* the background mode so it cancels any immediate scan job in progress (designed only for foreground use) to switch to background operations where there is no scan job.  The scheduling happening twice happens because the first `BeaconManager:startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion` and the `BeaconManager:setBackgroundMode` both trigger a "reschedule" process.  You can avoid all of this churn by calling `BeaconManager:setBackgroundMode:` first, earlier in your init process. That way the library is already in background mode when you call `BeaconManager:startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion` and things will work more smoothly.
2. The way the Android Job scheduler works is that if you set a periodic job at the most frequent (~15 minute) interval, it doesn't run right away.  So when the library starts back up in background mode, it won't do anything until the next interval starts.  This interval might be quite soon, or it could be as long as 25 minutes.  It would be possible to optimize this process by scheduling an immediate scan job if we determine the last one has not been run in a long time through some persisted timestamp.  This is a reasonable optimization that could be added to the library by preparing a pull request if you are interested in working on one.
3. The library only sets up the low-power intent-delivered scan after a scan cycle completes as this is the normal course of operations.  I agree that if the app is killed, it won't necessarily be set up as soon as possible when the app restarts.  The easiest way to optimize this is to complete the optimization proposed in (2) above, which would solve this problem as a side effect.
4. If you don't want to harm the accuracy of distance estimates, you want the transmitter power of your hardware beacons to be as high as possible and you want the advertising rate to be as high as possible.  Fewer packets per second give fewer statistical samples to work with and increases noise on the distance estimates.  Lower output power increases the noise floor relative to the signal, and gives very little margin in detectable difference between RSSI at 1 meter vs. 10 meter.  I understand that high transmitter power and high advertising rates significantly affect the lifespan of battery-powered beacons.  However, IMO if you reduce the transmitter power enough to save battery or reduce the advertising rate below, say, 5 Hz, then you should probably give up on distance estimates.
5. How best to use the library really depends on your use case.  If scans every ~15 minutes are good enough for your use case, you should probably stick with background mode.   I am not sure if the hack you describe will work to make the library behave how you want without modifications.  You could try, but it might end up taking more time than simply making the change as described in point (2) above.
6. In theory Android does have hardware-backed API support for quick callbacks associated with beacons disappearing.  Unfortunately, however, Android's Doze feature makes this unreliable and worthless for most use cases.  See my summary of work on this [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/706)

Comment: 2. I am interested, but I need further clarifications. In the case the application get's killed, on Android 10 from my testing it takes 10 minutes to run the 1st scheduled ScanJob. I consider this to be a reasonable pause of scanning. What happens with a previous scheduled ScanJob if the app it's killed, it's discarded? In this case, would the timestamp comparison do any good, if it takes at least 10 minutes? According to point 1 the immediate scan jobs are designed only for foreground use. Does that mean that this optimization would be possible only if running the app as a foreground service?

Comment: 4. I don't have a power consumption dependency. For example I want to know if I am in room A or room B in an apartment, if the TX power is big, it wouldn't make any difference since it would see both of them. That's why I reduced the power explicitly. So leaving behind the noise, would the existing distance algorithms based on the mobile device still work? If you have any other recommendation please share.

Comment: 5. Here I don't know if I've made myself understood. The point 2 I consider it an optimisation when the application get's killed, not to wait for the 1st scheduled scan job to happen. But here the described steps are to figure out when I exit a region to immediately install back the low power HW filter. Use case: application is in background mode, I enter room A, HW filter it's triggered, run foreground scanning until room A beacon is not seen, install HW filter, switch to background. Or maybe you understood from the 1st place. What do you think?

Comment: (2) a previously scheduled job is not affected by killing the app from the task switcher.  An immediate job may be scheduled in the background, but currently the library does not do so.  (4) you're better off leaving beacons at max power and then examining RSSI or distance calcs to determine if you are far away.  While imperfect, this will be far more reliable than  relying on weak transmitters fading out predictably. (5) This is more complex than needed.  If you don't care about battery usage on beacon or phone, just run a foreground service, keep sacnning in foreground mode all the time.